# Slack: Slash Command - 403 error on PHP/JSON request

Tags: php, json, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

My Slash Commands in Slack suddenly stopped working 2 moneths ago.

The setup is relatively simple:

- Using simple Slash commands with a slack app built only for this reason
- Adding a PHP page to a website to handle the slack command
- PHP script returns JSON response for slack to handle

I stripped down the PHP code to the following (for testing purpose):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // response to slack in JSON

$jsonReturn = array();

$jsonReturn['response_type'] = "in_channel";
$jsonReturn['text'] = 'TEST MESSAGE HERE.'; 
die(json_encode($jsonReturn)); // exit JSON with die()
```

In slack I get the following error message:

*Darn - that slash command didn't work (error message: `403_client_error`). Manage the command at APPNAME.*

I tried the following to solve the issue:

- changed request URL from HTTPS to HTTP
- enabled and disabled verification token

If I open the PHP site directly on my desktop or mobile phone I can see the correct JSON return.

Slack is running on our company network, but I suppose the error appeared with a change of the slack API, but I really don't know what change could have caused this.

Thank you!

Comment: 403 forbidden. check the URL slack calls, are you sure it's the same?

Comment: Yes, I copied the Request URL from 'edit command' form and on the browser it shows me the JSON result, but slack doesn't receive it.

Comment: The 403 error would indicate that Slack is not authorized to access your URL. Since you seam to be on a company network its likely that there has been a change on the company firewall, now preventing Slack access. (And no, Slack is not running on your company network, its a cloud service). You can fix this by migrating your script to a public web server, use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or talk to your company's security team to open the firewall. (Also, the API for slash command responses has NOT changed)

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the clarifications.
I tested the JSON result with http://echo.jsontest.com/ and with this public server test it works. I will now see with the security team.